# .Net core, Ef7 deploy to production

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I Have my core2.0 project finally production ready,

Bummer, can't deploy it ot Azure without migrations. (All migrations are in the code).

database ready (Empty)

Project ready (ok in local with localdb)

Now,

How can I applly all migration in production on "publish" in VS2017 of my app ?

So far my best guess is : Extract dacpac from localdb, manually apply it to Azure, change connection string.

But I hope where is a better way !

Edit :

Edit2 : Removed useless rant

Comment: There seem to be enough tutorials out there. Can you explain which step you are stuck on?

Comment: Hi,
It’s the problem There is NO tutorials on publishing Core2.0 web app to Azure.. Honestly, right Now I wish I did a simple MVC 4.5… 
I have “Publish fail, check connection string” error message. I’m 100% positive DataBase is up  running and credentials are good.

Comment: As nvoigt said, what is it that you're actually stuck on? What have you searched online for, in an effort to find an answer?  Also, for future reference, please take a look at this page on how to best ask questions on Stack Overflow in order to get the best answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I feel stupid. 
With core2 there is no more need to manually encode things like’&’ (=&) 
In new config you can just put it like it is “&blalalala”.